# Show a list in index.html with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using SpringBoot y Thymeleaf.

How could i do to display a list of product in index.html at the moment that page is loaded?

Currently products.html shows all the products from the bd and  index.html shows the fragment  with the header of the form of products.html but I do not know how to make to display the products.

if i'm wrong with my approach,how is the right way to do it?

index.html

```
<body>
<section layout:fragment="custom-content">
    <br> <br>
    <div class="container">
        <section th:replace="products :: content"></section>
                <br> <br>
        <h2>This is index.html</h2>
        </div>
```

this is  index.html with products.html fragment 
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7B4W.png)

products.html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div th:fragment="content">

        <h3>This is the fragment from products.html</h3>

        <h2>List of products</h2>
        <table class="table table-stripped">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Image Url</th>
                <th>List</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>

            <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
                <td th:text="${product.id}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.description}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.imageUrl}"></td>
                <td><a th:href="${'/products/numArt/' + product.numArt}">View</a></td>
                <td><a>Edit</a></td>
                <td><a>Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button>New Product</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

this is products.html
[products.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrL9O.png)

controller

```
@GetMapping("/products")
public String listProducts(Model model) {
    System.out.println("Get all products...");
    model.addAttribute("products", productRepository.findAll());
     return "products";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding `products` object in your products.html not with the fragments. So make another method something like below.

```
@GetMapping("/products/fragment")
public ModelAndView listOfProducts() {
     ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index::custom-content");
    mv.addObject("products", productRepository.findAll());
     return mv;
    }
```

and call this by ajax from your index.html. add below lines in your index file

```js
<script th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     loadData();
       });
       
     function loadData(){
     $.ajax({
     type: 'get',
     url: /*[[ @{'/product/fragment'} ]]*/,
     
     success: function(data){
     $('.container').html(data);
    },
     async:false
   })
     
     
     }
     </script>
```

```html
<body>
<section >
    <br> <br>
    
    
    <div class="container">
    <div th:fragment="custom-content">
        <section th:replace="products :: content"></section>
                <br> <br>
        <h2>This is index.html</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>....
```

hope this helps.

Comment: How have you call this method? Have you used any ajax?

Comment: Maybe its that,i added  th:action="@{products/fragment}"  like this <section th:replace="products :: content"  th:action="@{products/fragment}" >    can you tell me how should i make the call?

Comment: That's not the right way. You should read thymeleaf documentation first. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks @AritraPaul !!!! just change to this  url: '/product/fragment' , without  @, curly braces  or brackets